# Data sharing between multiple salesforce orgs

Tags: force.com, community

What are the option available for data sharing between multiple salesforce orgs? How does the admin monitor two orgs ...any magic control avilable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use Salesforce to Salesforce feature where you can set up a publish subscriber model and whenever you enter data into one organisation it will be shared with the other organisation . It's out of the box functionality, easy to configure. You can find more information here : https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=business_network_intro.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

I know 3 solutions which I used, might be there are another ways to do that.

1. Informatica Cloud. [Read more about it.](http://www.informaticacloud.com/products/data-quality-and-master-data-management/multi-org-consolidation.html) I guess that you can search a similar products via AppExchange.
2. Create your own set of scripts for migration data between org using [Apex Data loader console interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line), your preferable shell (cmd/powershell for Windows, bash for Mac and Linux) and Cron
3. Develop your own Data synchronization manager inside the Salesforce.com using Apex & web services which can be installed to your orgs via a managed package.

I do believe that if you have pretty simple data schema than the second way is preferable, but for more complicated cases you have to choose between 1st and 3rd options.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to have a look at the [Cross Organizational Data Sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cod_overview.htm) pilot. However, the 'spoke' orgs will only have ready-authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Bedrock Data has a pre-built Salesforce.com connector that can be used to connect multiple Salesforce orgs. Standard Salesforce objects (accounts, contacts, opportunities, leads, tasks, cases, users) can be connected and de-duplicated across org's.

Bedrock Data is also commonly used to connect Salesforce to other sales & marketing tools.  For more info see https://www.bedrockdata.com/bedrock-integrations#.featured

Comment: Are you affiliated with this product? Please take a moment to read [How to not be a spammer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).